# Best schema to implement multiple attributes for multiple entities?

Tags: laravel, database-design

I am designing a survey system database. There are multiple entities in the system like 'surveys', 'questions', 'options', 'users', 'survey_instance' etc. each of these entities have multiple attributes like surveys have 'time-limit', 'if questions should be presented randomly' (15 other attributes like that, not all surveys will have all these attributes). Questions will also have multiple optional attributes.

I was wondering what would be the best way to implement this kind of business situation in schema.

One option is that, i add one column for each possible attribute in the main table like adding 17 columns in Survey table and 7-8 odd columns in question table. But this option will yield multiple columns with too many null values. Doesn`t seem best.

Second option I thought was to add one extra table to store each attribute with a forein key as main table ID. for example a table with the name 'survey_attributes' with survey_id as foreign key and attribute ID and value other columns. This will yield one row for each attribute assigned to each entity.

Third option, I think could be that I have one table to define attributes and one table to store values for all attribut-entiry combination. But I could not really think through this.

Can anyone please help me understand what is the best database design in this scenario?

I am using Laravel 5.4 for backend and VueJs as frontend. The database design must be easy to create and update those attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm purposing you a fourth option. Build an associative array with all the optional attributes you want to set for a particular instance, serialize (`serialize()` or `json_encode()`) and save it to a field on your entity tables.

This solution is good enough if you're not planing to use your optional attributes in mysql queries (like SELECT statements).
You will also have to re encode the array any time you want to change a particular attribute so I would use it mainly if those attributes are meant to be read most of the time and modifying is a rare case.
You can even set up [accessors and mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators)s on your Eloquent model to ease your work with it.

Comment: Good idea, thank you. I can not really use it as my attributes should  be searchable for most entities.